# How to recyclerview bind view holder one time in recyclerview that multiple view holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to bind view holder only one time by this holder has one in recyclerview

example code

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == FEED_ITEM) {
        return new FeedViewHolder(new StoryListItem(context));
    } else if (viewType == SUGGEST_FRIEND_ITEM) {
        return new SuggestFriendViewHolder(new FeedSuggestFriendListItem(context));

    } else {
        return new EmptyViewHolder(new EmptyViewListItem(context));

    }
}

 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if(position==0){
    return SUGGEST_FRIEND_ITEM;

   }else{
    return FEED_ITEMว

   }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof FeedViewHolder) {
        ((FeedViewHolder) holder).fillData(newFeeds.get(position).getData());


    } else if (holder instanceof SuggestFriendViewHolder) {
        ((SuggestFriendViewHolder) holder).fillData();
}
```

I want to bindViewHolder suggestFriendViewHolder only one time

My problem is when scroll to first position (position = 0 ) from other position and suggestFriendViewHolder bind data every time when scroll to position = 0 . I want to bind data suggestFriendViewHolder one time.

Comment: What do you mean by "one time"?  Binding it a single time that the view holder is called may cause it to appear for an instant and then disappear.  The holders create/bind may be called multiple times when drawing the screen. If the user scrolls the first item off the screen and then back on, would you expect the friend row to still be there?

Comment: Ok , Thank . friend row is viewpager when bind data this row I set notifydatasetchange of viewpager and it 's lag when appear this row , How to fix it ? Thank PS. I use data from api and I want to use viewpager in recyclerview like facebook but It 's lag when scroll to appear this suggest friend row .